# show a rows depending on the number input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to dynamic add(clone)/remove div with inputs depends on the user input.
If the user changes input number to 4 or 10 it must show div 4 or 10 times.

Also, I need to modify the input name in cloned div (just like name_1).

Now I trying to do it in this way:

```
    var $row    = $('.row-with-fields');
    var $clone = $row.clone();

    $(".qty").on("keyup keydown change",function(event){
        $qty = $(this).val(); // how many rows I needs

        for(var i = 0; i < $qty; i++){
            $row.after($clone.addClass('row_'+i));
        }

    });
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? Also, its not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it like that:

```
    var $row    = $('.rsvp-qty-fields');

    $(".tribe-ticket-quantity").on("keyup keydown change",function(event){
        $qty = $(this).val();
        $rowsExist = $('.rsvp-qty-fields').length;

        if ($rowsExist < $qty) {

            for(var i = $rowsExist; i < $qty; i++){
                var $clone = $('.rsvp-qty-fields:first').clone().removeClass('receiver');
                $clone.find('.receiver').remove()
                $row.after($clone.addClass('row_'+i));
            }
            console.log('add');

        } else if($rowsExist > $qty) {
            for(var i = $rowsExist; i > $qty; i--){
                if (!($rowsExist <= 1)) {
                 $('.rsvp-qty-fields-wraper').children('.rsvp-qty-fields').last().remove();
                } else {
                  console.log('stop remove');
                }

        }
          console.log('remove');

     } else {

          console.log('equal');

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider two cases:

1-Clone() function is reference to element

2-You should check the number of event firing (i only use `change` event)

```
var $row = $('.row-with-fields');   

$(".qty").on("change",function(event){
    $qty = $(this).val(); // how many rows I needs

    for(var i = 0; i < $qty; i++){
        var $clone = $('.row-with-fields:first').clone();
        $row.after($clone.addClass('row_'+i));
    }

});
```